# Getting error 400 while passing put request in angular to backend in spring boot

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, put

This is my backend code for the put request.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200/")
@PutMapping("/updateItemQty/{id}")
public void updateItemQty(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,@RequestBody Items item) {
    service.updateItemQuantity(item,id);
}
```

This is what I'm passing from the front end

.ts file

```
this._service.updateItemQuantity(this.curItem.id, this.curItem).subscribe(user => {
    console.log("item updated successfully")
  },
    error => console.log("failure")
  )
```

And this is my service.ts code.

```
public updateItemQuantity(id: any, item: ItemsR): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.put<any>("http://localhost:8080/updateItemQty/id", item);
  }
```

I'm stucking here from very long time . pls help me with this.

Comment: can you confirm this is correct with your code? `return this._http.put<any>("http://localhost:8080/updateItemQty/id", item);` because I think it should be `return this._http.put<any>("http://localhost:8080/updateItemQty/" + id, item);`

Comment: Hi , I don't think it is making any difference cause I'm getting the same error by changing to `this._http.put<any>("http://localhost:8080/updateItemQty/" + id, item);`

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @Sheetal your request does not send `id` variable's value but just text id, you should check your request params. then now your backend actual has problem, please update your question with error response or stack trace on backend console

Comment: it should be like
`return this._http.put<any>(\`http://localhost:8080/updateItemQty/${id}\`, item)`